# Изменение дива

Tags: jquery, javascript

Помогите решить проблему, нужно сделать так...

Если твое в DIV'e текст = Привет, то его изменять на Пока.. чот не могу разобраться!

```
if ($(this).text() == "Privet") { $(this).text(poka) };
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да в общем-то все правильно:

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div").click(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == "Hi") {
                $(this).text("Bye");
            }
        });
    });
</script>                                                               
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
    <div>Hi</div>
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Клик по диву Hi превращает Hi в Bye, а клик по Yo - нет.

Comment: спасибо! столько думал. а тут так просто.. извините что не могу плюсанутЬ! спасибо еще раз!